# How to scroll the screen using the middle click?

Tags: mouse, scrolling

On Windows, most programs with large, scrollable text containers (e.g. all browsers, most word processors and IDEs) let you press the middle mouse button and then move the mouse to scroll. This scrolling is smooth and allows you to scroll very quickly using just the mouse.

When I've used Linux on *laptops*, two-finger scrolling performs roughly the same function; it's easy to scroll down a page quickly (much more quickly than one can by scrolling a mouse wheel) but the scrolling remains smooth enough to allow precise positioning.

I am unsure how to achieve the same thing when running Linux on a Desktop with a mouse. As far as I can tell after a whole bunch of Googling, there are neither application-specific settings to swap to Windows-style middle mouse button behaviour, nor any system-wide settings to achieve the same effect.

Just to make this concrete, let's say - if it's relevant - that I'm asking in the context of Firefox, Google Chrome, Gedit and Eclipse on a recent version of either Mint (what I use at home) or Ubuntu (what I use at work). I suspect this is a fairly distro-agnostic and application-agnostic question, though.

As far as I can tell, my options for scrolling are:

- Scroll with the mousewheel - slow!
- Use the PgUp / PgDn keys - jumps a huge distance at a time so can't be used for precise positioning, and is less comfortable than using the mouse
- Drag the scroll bar at the right hand side of the screen up and down like I used to do on old Windows PCs with two-button mice. This is what I do in practice, but it's just plain less comfortable than Windows-style middle-mouse scrolling; on a huge widescreen, it takes me most of a second just to move the cursor over from the middle of the screen to the scrollbar, and most of a second to move it back again, and I have to take my eyes off the content I'm actually scrolling to do this.

None of these satisfy me! This UI issue is the single thing that poisons my enjoyment of Linux on desktops and almost makes me wish I was using a laptop touchpad instead of a mouse. It irritates me enough that I've concluded that either I'm missing some basic Linux UI feature that solves this problem, or I'm just an oversensitive freak and it doesn't even bother anyone else - but I'm not sure which.

So my questions are:

1. Does Windows-style middle mouse button scrolling exist anywhere in the Linux world, or is it really purely a Windows thing? In particular, do any Linux web browsers let you use Windows-style scrolling?
2. Are there any mechanisms for scrolling pages that exist in Linux but not in Windows, especially ones that perform the role I've described?
3. Any other solutions that I'm missing?

Comment: You call "holding down middle mouse and moving the mouse" "Windows-style" scrolling but I was never aware that there was anything Windows-specific about it.  I actually had no idea what you meant by "Windows-style" before I read through your question carefully.  You may want to edit your question to use a more enlightening term as I doubt many other people on this site will know what you mean.  As far as I can remember that was fairly standard behavior even on Linux - it's probably just a matter of mouse configuration and whether holding down the mouse wheel registers as middle mouse button.

Comment: @jw013 I've never seen a Linux install where this behavior existed; middle mouse button always seems to just be Paste, and Googling suggests there's no way to turn off the middle-mouse paste behavior (which implies to me no way to turn on middle-mouse scroll behavior - but I'm not sure, which is why I asked here).

Comment: @jw013 BTW, if you can suggest a more enlightening term I'll use it, but as far as I know this behavior has no proper/official name and I can't think of a succinct and clear name to give it - which is why I described it carefully in my first paragraph instead.

Comment: I actually switched to a scroll-wheel-less trackball mouse a while ago so all of this is recollection.  I'd probably call it "middle mouse scrolling".  If I remember correctly, paste only triggered on a simple click, scrolling happened if you held the button down and moved the mouse around.  I might have had some settings in my `xorg.conf` that helped (I tend to copy over my old `xorg.conf` customizations to new installs so I don't remember exactly).  If you are using GNOME try poking around in your mouse preferences and see if there's anything there.

Comment: @MarkAmery Just in case you didn't already find this, see [Gilles' answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102011/21952) to a similar question. The method described by Gilles will enable scroll wheel emulation across all X.Org applications, not just Firefox.

Comment: There are some decent answers here, but it's worth nothing that they are not the same as Windows autoscroll, which is modal: click once to turn it on, and scrolling happens at a speed based on the distance the mouse is moved from the original click. The Firefox autoscroll does this as well.  The libinput-based answers scroll while the mouse is depressed only. If there's a system-wide modal autoscroll that I missed please let me know.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The feature you are talking about is called "Auto-Scrolling". It lets you press and hold the middle mouse button and move your mouse to scroll smoothly. In Linux, the default behavior for this action (pressing middle mouse button) is generally pasting text.

However, there is a preference setting in Firefox and an extension available for Chrome/Chromium which would let you use the middle mouse button for scrolling and activate this feature.

### Firefox

- Open the "Options" tab: "≡" (Open menu) → "Options".
- Navigate to "General" (it should open to "General" by default).
- Scroll down to "Browsing". 
  Under "Browsing", you will find the "Use autoscrolling" option. Put a check mark beside this to activate this functionality in Firefox.

  Or just search for "autoscrolling" using the search bar.

[image: Firefox Preferences tab with autoscrolling highlighted]

  In older versions of Firefox: "Edit" → "Preferences" → "Advanced" → "General" → "Browsing" → "User autoscrolling". 
  Click on the below for a larger image.
  [image: User autoscrolling option in older versions of Firefox]

### Chrome/Chromium

For Chrome/Chromium we can use an Extension called "AutoScroll" (from kaescripts.blogspot.com).

- Go to [this link on Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoscroll/occjjkgifpmdgodlplnacmkejpdionan?hl=en) (obviously using Chrome/Chromium).
- Click on the button labeled "+ ADD TO CHROME" to install this extension.

  [image: Chrome Extension]
- Click on "Add" in the Confirmation Dialog Box.

### Electron apps

In some Electron apps like Visual Studio Code, Spotify, and Discord, you can add `--enable-blink-features=MiddleClickAutoscroll` to the launch arguments. Depending on whether the program is running an Electron version that supports it, autoscroll will be enabled.

### Other Applications

As far as other applications are concerned, I haven't yet found a solution for them. Anyways, it's the tall webpages that create most of the problems for which both Firefox and Chrome/Chromium have a solution.

Comment: Awesome. I will try out the extensions at work tomorrow and then accept this answer. I'm fairly convinced by now that for most other applications there simply isn't a solution.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Yup... For me this is the most annoying thing in Linux... It still annoys me in one of my folders which contains lots and lots of files... Otherwise, as I said, this feature is mostly useful for webpages, for which we have a solution at hand... :)

Comment: It works! Yay! :)

Comment: Funny it does not work on some websites like `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps?hl=en` itself.

Comment: @dashesy Autoscrolling doesn't work on some websites because they hijack the scrolling behavior of the browser through JavaScript. You would find that autoscrolling doesn't work on those websites when using Windows as well where autoscrolling is the Operating System feature.

Comment: On Chrome Web Store and other such special websites extensions are disabled.

Comment: This is the better answer and should be accepted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421672/115227

Comment: Y-E-S-!!! It works! :-D (for Firefox)

Comment: "_The feature you are talking about is called Auto-Scrolling_" - that might be true for Firefox and the Chrome/ium extension (and that's very unfortunate), but in general, no. Auto-scrolling is... automatic scrolling (like in Evince when you right-click the document and select `Autoscroll`, then it'll scroll automatically).

Answer (score 38):

This will work with all your applications without the need of installing anything.

Get your input deviceID. In my case was 11.

```
xinput list
```

If you want, list available properties with `xinput list-props <deviceID>`. If you are using libinput (the future/present), almost all properties will start with *libinput*. For [`evdev`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102011) check [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/868173/349837).

#### With [`libinput`](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/pages.html)

Set mouse properties

```bsh
xinput set-prop 11 "libinput Scroll Method Enabled" 0, 0, 1  # This is button
xinput set-prop 11 "libinput Button Scrolling Button" 2      # This is middle mouse. Already 2 by default
```

Description from `man libinput`:

- **libinput Scroll Method Enabled** 3 boolean values (8 bit, 0 or 1), in order "two-finger", "edge", "button".  Indicates which scroll method is currently enabled n this device.
- **libinput Button Scrolling Button** 1 32-bit value. Sets the button number to use for button scrolling. This setting is independent of the scroll method, to nable button scrolling the method must be set to button-scrolling and a valid button must be set.

---

- [You can add this](https://askubuntu.com/a/461173/349837) to a shell script and run it at login.
- Like mouse wheel, with the same movement while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> will zoom in/out page. <kbd>Ctrl + 0</kbd> to reset.
- This work with X and [probably with Wayland](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libinput/).

Comment: *"For `evdev` [do one thing]. With `libinput`: [do another thing]."* How do I know which of those applies to me? I've never heard of either before reading this answer.

Comment: @MarkAmery I don't know a straightforward way, kernel module (`modinfo $(lsmod|grep -iE "input" | col1)`) [doesn't show it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131447/209677). But after you get your deviceID and list properties, if you are using `libinput` almost all properties will start with that word. Also you will have `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` package installed, `libinput-list-devices` command will list your device (certainly on `/proc/bus/input/devices`). If using X you will find more info diggin on `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.

Comment: This is the better answer and should be accepted.

Comment: I tried this and found that not only it doesn't work in all applications, but also, in those where it does work, it feels very hackish and not Windows-like at all.

Comment: @Marc.2377 Is there a single Linux feature or program that tries to behave like something on Windows that _can't_ be described in that manner?  :(

Comment: how to reverse scrolling direction?

Comment: @Mah35h Do you mean natural scrolling? Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/868173/349837)

Comment: Wow! `xinput set-prop 'PixArt USB Optical Mouse' 'libinput Scroll Method Enabled' 0 0 1` was all I needed for my 3M joystick ergonomic mouse. `xinput list-props 'PixArt USB Optical Mouse'` said the scroll button was already 2 as the default, like you said. Works way better than expected. Thanks, @PabloA!

Comment: I eventually created a /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/91-pixart-usb-optical-mouse.conf file with the following contents. It required a reboot, not just a reattach, to take effect.

```
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58900/how-to-scroll-the-screen-using-the-middle-click
# xinput set-prop 'PixArt USB Optical Mouse' 'libinput Scroll Method Enabled' 0 0 1
# Required a reboot.
Section "InputClass"
  # xinput list
  Identifier "PixArt USB Optical Mouse"
  MatchUSBID "093a:2510"
  MatchIsPointer "on"
  Option "ScrollMethod" "button"
  Option "ScrollButton" "2"
EndSection
```

Comment: This worked great with my 3M optical mouse EM550GPS.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

### TRY THIS : For auto scroll functionality in firefox

```
firefox > preferences > search auto scroll and enable it
```

in firefox which comes with vanilla ubuntu its disabled sometimes 
if you want to further tweak your mouse settings as in the control panel below you might want to **install gnome-tweak-tool**

> sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
>   [image]

**SECOND ALTERNATIVE :**

- change the middle mouse button behaviour through **xinput**.
- type the below code to probe input devices and peripherals

> xinput list

- and you should get similar display as below:
  [image]
- now my mouse is 9
- now write this in terminal

> xinput set-prop 9 "libinput Scroll Method Enabled" 0, 0, 1

- now check the behaviour of mouse when you press the middle key and move up or down in any application with vertical scroll [big text /document].

Comment: The OP is talking about an issue with *all* Linux programs,not just Firefox.

Comment: xinput is working and tested also useful for *all Linux programs,not just Firefox*. 
gnome tweak is also useful for *all Linux programs,not just Firefox*.
i updated the answer .

Comment: Thank you, this works!

Answer (score 1):

Decided to automate Pablo A's answer, since I found it to be the best one (as it works in all apps, not just Firefox).

Save this file as a script (for example: `~/setup_middle_click_scrolling.sh`), make it executable with `chmod +x`, then run it (you can delete it after you run). It enables middle-click to scroll and also adds a startup script so that you get the functionality whenever you log in.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Enables middle click to scroll (like Windows).
set -e

: ${SCRIPT_PATH:=~/.config/autostart/middle_click_to_scroll.sh}
: ${DESKTOP_PATH:=~/.config/autostart/middle_click_to_scroll.desktop}

# Create dirs if they don't exist.
echo "$SCRIPT_PATH" "$DESKTOP_PATH" | xargs dirname | xargs mkdir -p

# Create a script that can be run on-demand.
# When run, it enables middle-click to scroll.
cat > "$SCRIPT_PATH" << EOF
#!/bin/bash

# Get device IDs of all devices containing "pointer"
pointer_ids=(\$(xinput list | grep pointer | perl -p -e 's@.*?id=(\d+).*@\1@'))

for pointer_id in "\${pointer_ids[@]}"; do
  # If the pointer supports scroll method, set middle click to scroll
  if xinput list-props "\$pointer_id" | grep 'Scroll Method Enabled' &>/dev/null; then
    xinput set-prop "\$pointer_id" 'libinput Scroll Method Enabled' 0 0 1
  fi
done
EOF
chmod +x "$SCRIPT_PATH"

# Create a desktop entry so it runs on startup.
cat > "$DESKTOP_PATH" << EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Middle click to scroll
Exec="$SCRIPT_PATH"
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=Initialization
Terminal=false
NoDisplay=true
EOF

"$SCRIPT_PATH"
```

Hopefully folks in the comments could point out whether this would work on all systems, but it works with my setup of `XFCE` + `libinput` + standard 3-button mouse.

Comment: Someone edited my post to change `"${pointer_ids[@]}"` to `"\${pointer_ids[@]}"` -- I don't know what shell you're using but that does not work in Bash, so I'm changing the answer back. I'm on bash 5.0.17.

Comment: As presented, this script did not work for me. I am not good at shell scripting, so I can't speak with confidence, but, it seems the commands within the middle_click_to_scroll.sh file are being executed *at the time the setup_middle_click_scrolling.sh script is run*, NOT at the time the middle_click_to_scroll.sh script is run. I don't think this is desired behavior. The person who edited your answer may have been trying to fix that. Personally, I worked around the bug in your script by simply copying the code to the middle_click_to_scroll.sh file manually. Apart from that, this worked! Thanks!

Comment: @mattarod you are right, those shell vars inside the `cat <<<EOF` block were being evaluated when that script was run. I edited it so that it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on ***Brandon Duffany's*** answer - his script didn't work on my system (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS) and after some debugging, I found it was likely because of the for loop. It behaved as if `pointer_ids` array was full of empty values and the script just kept returning `unable to find device`. I figured it was some bash trickery with badly recognized array values so I rewrote the loop.

I made smaller bash script file `<path-to-file>/middle-click-emulation.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Enables middle click to scroll (like Windows).
pointerids=($(xinput list | grep "pointer" | perl -p -e 's@.*?id=(\d+).*@\1@'))

for ((i = 0; i < ${#pointerids[@]}; i++))
do
  echo "Setting up for device id = ${pointerids[$i]}"
  # If the pointer supports scroll method, set middle click to scroll
  if xinput list-props ${pointerids[$i]} | grep 'Scroll Method Enabled' &>/dev/null; then
    xinput set-prop ${pointerids[$i]} 'libinput Scroll Method Enabled' 0 0 1
  fi
done
```

Manually created the desktop shortcut in `~/.config/autostart/middle_click_to_scroll.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Middle click to scroll emulation
Exec="<path-to-file>/middle-click-emulation.sh"
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=Initialization
Terminal=false
NoDisplay=true
```

And gave **executable privileges to both** the bash script and the desktop shortcut.

And then manually run the script cause I'm too lazy to reboot :-)

Thank you, Brandon :-)

PS: I think you can still use the Brandon's script which creates the desktop shortcuts for you if you replace just the for loop (watch out for the array name).

Comment: I encountered the same 'unable to find device' error code. I also found a workaround and I have a guess what the problem is, and it's not the for loop. I discuss it in my comment reply to his answer. Nonetheless, if I'd seen your comment before trying to fix the problem myself, it probably would have saved me a lot of time. Upvote for helpful answer.