# Linux Scroll Extension

Tags: kali-linux, scrolling

I've already searched for it in google or stackexchange but didn't find anything. Is there anything for linux (exactly Kali Linux) for scrolling with the scroll mouse button? I mean, you know, like when in Windows I click on scrollMouseButton while on scrollView, there appears and icon and when I move my mouse pointer up, it scrolls up. When down - scrolls down.

Comment: specifically about browsers, [here it is an answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58900/how-to-scroll-the-screen-using-the-middle-click) that might interest you

Comment: about all the X.Org applications [give a look at this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101867/make-mouse-movements-scroll-when-the-middle-button-is-held-down/102011#102011)